# How to list files from Shared with Me in google api

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm trying to list files and folders from Shared With Me (with children.list). I use the query string like this:

```
 'q'=sharedWithMe
```

But this only return my files and folder (that someone shared with me) that are in My Drive root too. I think it's because I put as id of parent 'root' but I can't find which id I've got to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if we can use `children.list` in this case, but I solve my problem using `files.list` with the query string `'q'='sharedWithMe'` because it only lists the children’s of Shared With Me. Anyway, if someone know how to use `children.list` for the same objective I'd like to know. : )